# Transfer Secret: AuthCode vs EPP code

Tags: dns, www

Talking about transfer secret:
What is the difference between AuthCode and EPP code and which one is the correct name.

The wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_secret is not clear on which is the correct name.

Comment: It says: "The code is officially called an AuthInfo Code and an Auth-Info code by ICANN and registry operators. It is alternatively called an auth code, a transfer key, a transfer secret, an EPP code, EPP authentication code, or EPP authorization code."  It's just an alternate name for the same thing.

Comment: @techie007, it does appear to be somewhat more nuanced than that, but yes, in plenty of cases, you could call them synonymous, especially nowadays since EPP is ubiquitous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensible Provisioning Protocol (EPP) is a set of common protocols used for domain registration in DNS, and it uses a code to verify and validate the authenticity of a domain name registration, to prevent several types of attacks on registrars that facilitate hijacking and impersonation attacks.

"Transfer Secret" is a generic name that covers what the code is and what its used for, independent of any particular implementation (such as EPP). Before there was EPP, each registrar used its own set of interfaces for domain registration, and they may implement some form of "transfer secret", for their non-EPP process, so "Transfer secret" just refers to the idea that some verification code is needed before allowing some actions like registrations and zone transfers, including those used by EPP.

Comment: I'm missing AuthCode comparison, it sounds more technical than Transfer secret. Indeed I was asking between EPP and Authcode..

Comment: AuthInfo code and EPP code are directly synonymous.